# jQuery prevent one item from being dropped into another list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists, each one with a unique ID.  I am wondering how I can prevent 
the parent-parent list the main one from dropping an entire outer section `<div>` into
an `<li> <div>` which already contains a `<ul> <li>` list of its own. In addition, the placeholder appears there too. I am wondering if there is a way to force the items that belong to the first list to stay there even if they move above another list with an item in the main global list.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Some code:

```
<ul id="main">
      <li>
           <div id="content"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="Section1">
            <ul id="section-list">
                 <li><div id="item1"><h2>Hello World</h2><li>
                 <li><div id="item2"><h2>Hello World</h2><li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
   <ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $("#main").sortable({
                 connectWith: "#main",
                 placeholder: 'placeholder',
                 forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                 start: function (e, ui) {
                     var elementHeight = ui.item.height();
                     ui.placeholder.height(elementHeight);
                 }
             });
```

My code now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('ul#main').sortable({
                 items: 'li:not(:last-child)',
                 placeholder: 'placeholder',
                 forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                 handle: '.grab-and-move-area',
                 start: function (e, ui) {
                     var elementHeight = ui.item.height();
                     ui.placeholder.height(elementHeight);
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
```

**EDIT: Added the last jsfiddle with original code:**

I copied all my original work, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/1/ <-- drag summary over books section and you'll see

**EDIT: Can somebody please tell me why this does not work as it should? Thanks!**

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle illustrating your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/

Comment: y'know, when you post a fiddle, you might at least make sure that you pay attention to the code hints so that your html is valid. And you might include the JS libraries that you are using.  Here is your fiddle with libraries included and html corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/3/  Now please make it act the way that you've described your problem.

Comment: Thanks @dnagirl I am not able to produce the same issue here, http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/9/ the placeholder of this one does not appear in the second ul li, but if I move it in the original work that I have pretty much the same code, a place holder appears between first li & second li in the second ul, this when I move the li from the first ul :(

Comment: If I drag the lorem ipsum li div and move it between the li tags in the second ul the placeholder does not show up here, but when I do the same in my other code it appears for some king of reason, not sure of why? Is there a possible way to force items with in a ul, so even if they move between li tags in another list the placeholder will not show up.

Comment: Can somebody please have a look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/1/  and tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stripped out your unnecessary html markup and I've wrapped your `ul#main` in a `<div>` This div allows you to connect all the `<ul>`s inside of it together with `.sortable()`.  Your placeholder shows and you can move list items from one level of hierarchy to another, including creating a new child list.

Using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui 1.9.2,

### html

```
<div id='sortablediv'>
  <ul id="main">
      <li id="content">
           Lorem ipsum..
      </li>
      <li id="Section1" class='section-head'>Section One
            <ul id="section-list1">
                <li id="item1">Hello World</li>
                <li id="item2">Hello Mars</li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Section2" class='section-head'>Section Two
            <ul id="section-list2">
                <li id="item3">Goodbye World</li>
                <li id="item4">Goodbye Mars</li>
            </ul>
      </li>    
   <ul>
</div>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $("#sortablediv ul").sortable({
                 connectWith: "#sortablediv ul", //connect all uls with all other uls in #sortablediv
                 placeholder: 'placeholder'
             });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/18/

reference: http://a.shinynew.me/post/4641524290/jquery-ui-nested-sortables

Comment: Thanks @dnagirl, but this does not really solve the issue, I want to force an item in the first ul and make sure that placeholder does not appear when I move it between li tags in other uls...

Comment: @John Smith: well, the placeholder is not appearing.  So, for example, you want to move 'Hello World' out of section One and make it a direct child of `<ul id='main'>`?

Comment: It's not appearing in this example, but in my original work that I am doing it keeps appearing, and I am not able to know why? I keep testing but the placeholder still appears.

Comment: I have different IDs for each <UL>

Comment: @JohnSmith: your original example has invalid html. So the javascript doesn't work because it can't read the DOM properly. Your `<li>`s aren't closed properly and they are full of unnecessary block elements, like `<div>` and '<h2>'. That's why your placeholder is a problem in your original example.

Comment: @JohnSmith: you can put id's on your `<ul>`s, but unless you want to be able to find a specific one, it's not really necessary.

Comment: I actually have: handle: '.grab-and-move-area',

Comment: Tried this as well, http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/16/ but still the placeholder does not appear as it does in the original...weird...

Comment: @JohnSmith: I've updated my answer. This should do it for you.

Comment: you just managed to produce the issue, the li in the main ul is now able to be dropped in an inner ul inside a main li, which is what I want to prevent. Hmm?

Comment: @JohnSmith: take out the connectWith and you won't be able to put anything in the internal uls.  I'm sorry for the misunderstanding; your prose is extremely difficult to interpret.

Comment: I did that, still the same issue occurs, not sure of why!

Comment: I just downloaded the latest UI and added a link to the latest jQuery.min.js still the exact same issue occurs, not sure of why, removing the connectWith should do the job.

Comment: My current jQuery includes: handle: '.grab-and-move-area',

Comment: I tested to remove the div tags and apply the same classes to the li tags, still no luck! :(

Comment: @JohnSmith: http://jsfiddle.net/S3836/26/ allows movement of Sections and movement of top level `<li>`s; it shows the placeholder; it does not allow movement into or out of sections. If this isn't what you want, then I can't help you.

Comment: That is what I want, but why doesn't my original code work? Hmm?

Comment: I have removed the connectWith and refreshed the page in the browser without any luck, tried to remove the dic tags between each li no luck! Where can the problem be really?

Comment: I copied all my original work, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/1/ <-- drag summary over books section and you'll see